# После переноса директории /var/log логи пишутся только под пользователем root

Tags: логирование, root, astra-linux

Было сделано так:

```
pvcreate /dev/sda4
vgcreate logs-vg /dev/sda5
lvcreate -l 100%FREE -n logs logs-vg
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/logs--vg-logs
mount /dev/mapper/logs--vg-logs /var/log
```

И внесены соответствующие изменения в fstab
После этого в /var/log может писать только root. Многие сервисы, например auditd и zabbix-agent не стартуют из-за того, что не могут создать лог-файл.

```
Could not open dir /var/log/audit (No such file or directory)
```

Как исправить не для одного сервиса, а для всех?

Comment: Раз директорию создал root, то и права на нее имеет только root. Надо изменить права на директорию.

Comment: Решила проблему копированием /var/log с другой машины с сохранением прав и структуры каталогов.